# Python's speed in operating system development

Tags: python

I have a question which has been on my mind for a while. I'm aware that languages like C are faster than Python and are therefore used to write operating systems. I've read somewhere that an operating system written in Python will be very slow. So here is my question:
As processor speed is continuously improved, does the execution speed of a particular language become less of a factor in operation system development? Will it be possible, in the future, to write an operating system solely in Python that will be running almost on the same speed with one written in C? Thank you.

Comment: If you increase processor speed, wouldn't C become even more faster?

Comment: That is obviously so. Assembly is faster than C but u don't see people writing OS's in assembly only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**General issues**

It's not possible to write an operating system in Python alone because Python is not self hosting.

C compilers like gcc has special "free standing" modes designed for operating system development (and other related tasks), where functions like `printf` aren't available (as you have to implement them yourself using assembler).

In Python functions like `print` are built-in (and can't just be removed), if you don't have an operating system then how would they be implemented?

Finally, even if you could disable all the parts of Python that relied on the operating system you still wouldn't be able to control the CPU. To enable things like paging and interrupts requires special assembler instructions, which Python can't generate. Additionally you need to place things in particular locations in memory, and Python has no raw pointers.

[This page](http://wiki.osdev.org/Languages) has a lot of useful information about using languages other than C for OS development.

**Speed**

You're right in that Python is only a constant factor slower than C. You can see that in many fields other than OS development dynamic languages are becoming more and more popular as CPUs become faster.

Operating system development is no different, so you'll actually find many real examples where Python is replacing parts of operating systems that would normally be written in C. An example is [fusepy](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy), which allows you to implement file system in Python.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: @NwaiwuGilbert It means that Python is not a powerful (in terms of low level capabilities) enough language to provide the tools for operating system development.

Answer (score 1):

No. Think about it: If Python is slower than C for a processor running at speed X, what can you say about the speed of Python vs. C for a processor running at speed 2X?

But then... You *can* write operating systems in dynamic languages. And people do. Once you bootstrap the interpreter. But this won't become mainstream. At least not anytime soon. Because: The mainstream operating systems are already... well... mainstream. And people want to use all that processing power in their new processors for... um... processing stuff. And not for providing the underpinnings to... um... process stuff.